# Блоки в Django шаблонах

Tags: python, django, шаблоны

Добрый день, уважаемые знатоки и эксперты. Вопрос задает обучающийся программированию.

Делаю по видеоуроку. Прописал всё как там, но не выводит текст в шаблоне через блоки. Открываю страницу, а блок container пуст. В чем может быть проблема? Скрины прикладываю. Уже час мучаюсь.
[image: Файл home.html]

[image: Файл base.html]

Answer (score 1):

Всё решил! Помогли, дали наводку. Оказывается в **views.py** стоял рендеринг на `base` шаблон, изменил на `home` - все заработало!